# Rolling count over window without NULL or repeated values

Tags: google-bigquery

Consider the follow window already grouped by `id` and sorted by timestamp in descending order.

| id | timestamp | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| foo | 10:50 | NULL |
| foo | 10:40 | a |
| foo | 10:30 | a |
| foo | 10:20 | NULL |
| foo | 10:10 | NULL |
| foo | 10:00 | b |
| foo | 9:50 | c |
| foo | 9:40 | NULL |
| foo | 9:30 | d |
| foo | 9:20 | NULL |

Given that a `val` will not appear again once a different value occurs. That is, I won't have `a,b,a` but `a,null,a` might appear. I want to generated a rolling count on the condition that `val` is not `NULL` or previously seen. That is, I'd like something like:

| id | timestamp | val | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| foo | 10:50 | NULL | 0 |
| foo | 10:40 | a | 1 |
| foo | 10:30 | a | 1 |
| foo | 10:20 | NULL | 1 |
| foo | 10:10 | a | 1 |
| foo | 10:00 | b | 2 |
| foo | 9:50 | c | 3 |
| foo | 9:40 | NULL | 3 |
| foo | 9:30 | d | 4 |
| foo | 9:20 | NULL | 4 |

So essentially a "collapsed" count. I've tried something like

```sql
SELECT *, COUNT(val) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp DESC) count
```

But this does not disregard `val` that's previous occured.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * except(first_seen),
  countif(first_seen and not val is null) over(order by timestamp desc) distinct_count
from (
  select *, 
    1 = row_number() over(partition by val order by timestamp desc) first_seen
  from table
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
with mytable as
(
    select 'foo' as id, time(10, 50, 0) as timestamp, NULL as val union all
    select 'foo' as id, time(10, 40, 0) as timestamp, 'a' as val union all
    select 'foo' as id, time(10, 30, 0) as timestamp, 'a' as val union all
    select 'foo' as id, time(10, 20, 0) as timestamp, NULL as val union all
    select 'foo' as id, time(10, 10, 0) as timestamp, 'a' as val union all
    select 'foo' as id, time(10, 0, 0) as timestamp, 'b' as val union all
    select 'foo' as id, time(9, 50, 0) as timestamp, 'c' as val union all
    select 'foo' as id, time(9, 40, 0) as timestamp, NULL as val union all
    select 'foo' as id, time(9, 30, 0) as timestamp, 'd' as val union all
    select 'foo' as id, time(9, 20, 0) as timestamp, NULL as val
)
select id, timestamp, val, (select count(distinct c) from unnest(cnt) as c) - 1 as count
from (
    select *, ARRAY_AGG(IFNULL(val,'dummy')) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp DESC) as cnt
    from mytable
)
```

[image]

Comment: This works fine except for the edge case `a,null`. I tried adding `IGNORE NULLS` to the `ARRAY_AGG` but it gave me `Analytic function array_agg does not support IGNORE NULLS or RESPECT NULLS.` Which seems weird cuz their documentation says recent releases now supports IGNORE NULLS or RESPECT NULLS

Comment: same problem for me